# Can we compress PDF files using javascript? If yes, how & If no, why?

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser, compression

I've implemented upload documents functionality on browser where a user can upload around 4-5 documents at a time. However, when we upload the documents having file size around 5MB and having slow internet connection(set slow 3G network in the browser's dev tools), we can not upload all the files due to internet timeout!

To upload documents successfully having large size and slow internet connection, I've compressed the images and it solves my issue. But the user can also upload PDF files of large size. How can we compress PDF files and then upload?

Comment: If you requirements allow to use HTML5 `FileReader` API, there are several JavaScript libraries (such as https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) for creating ZIP files at browser. Then you can upload it after creating with JavaScript.

Comment: @OsmanTuran: Thanks for your suggestion, but we're not allowed zip files to get uploaded!

Comment: Let me rephrase what I said at the user's PoV. The user selects documents and starts upload. Then JS code handles selected files and compress them into a single ZIP file and uploads it to server. Then server decompresses and uses files in the ZIP file. If you don't want to use ZIP in any way, you can upload each files by compressing with LZMA with JS. If you want to optimize PDF files and compress them without introducing another format, it's still possible. But, it's hard to get done in the browser. Please look at Precomp for recompressing PDFs: https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp

Comment: @OsmanTuran: Yes right, we can do like that!

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle, How did you solve this?

Comment: @Tanvi Agarwal: I didn't solve this issue as later we didn't need such thing to be handled! But can reffer the above comments to get better idea!

Comment: Any update on this? How did you solve this @AniruddhaShevle

Comment: @AliAbbas : Please refer this: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/OptimizerTest

Comment: @TanviAgarwal : Please refer this: pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/OptimizerTest

Answer (score 3):

I was asking myself the same question (can you reduce the size of a PDF client side only?) and it turns out that someone did it:

https://github.com/OpenToolKit/CompressPDF.

The script is working client-side only and is able to recompress the pictures of a PDF and even join different PDFs.

However, there is a [known limitation](https://github.com/OpenToolKit/CompressPDF/issues/4): the text in a PDF is rendered as an image first and then compressed, resulting in a quality loss.

It uses a [combination](https://github.com/OpenToolKit/CompressPDF/tree/master/js) of:

- [PDFKit](https://pdfkit.org/)
- [blob-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-stream)
- [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)
- [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)